# Why we need to make the variable as void after passing as prototype?

Tags: c

The below funtion already has the variable declaration as uint8_t. But still why inside the function we need to  declare it in different way?

```
bool cli_cdc_enable(uint8_t port)
{
    (void) port;

    cdc_connected = true;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to redeclare it. with the parentheses  around void, you're actually casting it to void then not using it.   Does that even compile?

Comment: This is done to suppress any compiler warning(s) which complains that the variable `port` is unused.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need. This kind of thing is usually to indicate to compiler warnings and lint tools that the variable is deliberately unused. It doesn't have any effect on what the function does.

Comment: I am thinking what can be the use case of this.If it is not required, why would we pass it to the function.

Comment: @GauravSehgal: Probably because this function is used as a callback somewhere.